# C++ реализация класса List, метод insert

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Реализую класс **List**, возникли проблемы с методом **Insert**. Данный метод работает также как и в библиотеки list, т.е. я передаю в функцию позицию куда вставить и само значение, при этом размер списка не увеличивается, он просто заменяет значение элемента на заданной позиции. В самое начало и в конец все правильно вставляет, а с остальным проблемы.

```
void insert(const int index, const T& value) {
    Element<T>* newelem = new Element<T>(value);

    int curindex = 0;
    Element<T>* cur = _front;
    while (cur != nullptr)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            //если введен index=0, при помощи конструктора я изменяю значения
            // первого элемента
            _front=new Element<T>(value,_front->GetNext(),_front->GetPrev());
        }
        if (index == _size-1)
        {
          //если введен index=size(размеру моего списка), при помощи 
          //конструктора я изменяю значения последнего элемента
        _back = new Element<T>(value, _back->GetNext(), _back->GetPrev());
        }
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (curindex == index-1)
        {
          //SetNext()-метод который указывает на следующий элемент
          //SetЗкум()-метод который указывает на предыдущий элемент
            newelem->SetNext(cur->GetNext());
            newelem->SetPrev(cur->GetPrev());
            cur->SetNext(newelem);
        }
        curindex++;
        cur = cur->GetNext();
    }
}
```

Как данный метод более правильно реализовать?

Comment: Я тут пишу программу, но почему-то неверно работает вызов `z = x*allowUser()-5`, не подскажете, почему? Не имея никакой информации ни о `x`, ни об `allowUser()` и даже об операторе `*`? *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас странная вставка получается: вот в первой строчке:

```
   Element<T>* newelem = new Element<T>(value);
```

вы создали новый элемент, а дальше:

```
    if (index == 0)
    {
        //если введен index=0, при помощи конструктора я изменяю значения
        // первого элемента
        _front=new Element<T>(value,_front->GetNext(),_front->GetPrev());
    }
```

выделяется еще один. При этом не удаляя память под `_front`. То есть вы два раза память теряете. Тоже самое после строки `if (index == _size-1)`

Можно примерно так сделать:

```
void insert(const int index, const T& value) {
 Element<T>* current = _front;
 for(int i = 0; i <= index; ++i )
       current = current->GetNext();
  
 current->setValue(value); 
}
```

Добавте метод  `setValue` в класс `Element` и не нужно лишний раз выделять динамическую память. Это схематичный пример без учета того, что пользователь может передать неверный индекс.